# Protractor get console variable value

Tags: selenium, protractor

In Firefox browser developer tool console, I type var a = libraryform.firstname

It returns the firstname value entered by user for that form.

I am new to protractor and selenium. How can I call library.firstname in protractor to get the value of fistname?

Comment: What is `libraryform`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Javascript Executor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) to execute the javascript which you able to get them working in developer console against your application.

For e.g.,

this returns web-element which retrieved through javascript executed in browser.

```
var element = browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('identifier1')");
```

Refer [this page](http://www.webdriverjs.com/javascript-executor-protractor/)  for more examples

If this single line returns required value in browser console, then the protractor code should be some thing like this,

```
var name = browser.executeScript('return libraryform.firstname')
```

If you need too many lines of js, you can specify with semicolon separated,

```
var name = browser.executeScript("var element=$('.dropdown-toggle').eq(0); return element.text();")
```